# java JGraphx save as an image

Tags: jgraphx

Does anyone know how to export JGraphx as an image in any format? If not, then  does anyone know any other java library that will let me create simple diagrams and then save it  as an image?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should do it for PNG format:

```
BufferedImage image = mxCellRenderer.createBufferedImage(graph, null, 1, Color.WHITE, true, null);
ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File("C:\\Temp\\graph.png"));
```

Where

- `graph` is your mxGraph object. (Note `mxCellRenderer` is a reference to a class not a variable, so `mxCellRenderer.createBufferedImage` is a static method call).
- `"PNG"` is the format, and can be JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP and WBMP out of the box. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html) for more details.