# How to plot graph in java and to save as Image

Tags: java, image, graph

I would create a java program to save a graph as image `PNG` for example with the following data:

```
x-axis: 01  02  03  04  05  06  07  08  09  10 
y-axis: 610 635 659 680 699 712 722 732 736 749
```

Comment: Your question is very broad meaning you're likely coming here too soon in your development process. I suggest that you break the big problem into small constituent steps and then try to solve each single step one at a time. Come back with your specific answerable question and your code if stuck after attempting this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically you'd do that following these steps. Actually you have to first learn how to work with particular parts:

1. Save these coordinates to an `array` or a `List`.
2. Draw the content using `javafx` or any graphics library.
3. Read the: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2450090?tstart=0
4. In case of using `javafx`, you can capture its canvas with `canvas.snapshot(..)`
5. Save the file using `ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(wim, null), "png", file);`
6. Hooray!

I recommend you to start with learning all about variables, data types, arrays, loops and lists/maps. Don't start with 2D drawing unless you can handle with data :)

Comment: provided great source of information to start with javafx

Answer (score 1):

Try dotty.exe to create graphs. Use graphviz open source.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [JGraphX](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/manual_javavis.html#1.5) to create graphs in java.
You could find maven dependency on [github](https://github.com/vlsi/jgraphx-publish).
To save tree graph try [java JGraphx save as an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432160/java-jgraphx-save-as-an-image)